# Divide by zero error in SQL even though I excluded the zero cases?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is the code that I've been trying to run:

```
SELECT C.* FROM
(SELECT 
B.[OUTSIDE_ROW],
B.[INSIDE_ROW],
B.[r_HU_vac_ns],
B.[r_HU_vac_ns_MOE],
CASE WHEN B.[r_HU_vac_ns] = 0 THEN 999 ELSE B.[r_HU_vac_ns_MOE]/B.[r_HU_vac_ns] END AS [PCT]
FROM
(SELECT 
A.[OUTSIDE_ROW], 
A.[INSIDE_ROW], 
(A.[HU_VACANT] - A.[HU_VACANT_SEASONAL_RECREATIONAL])/A.[HU_VACANT] AS [r_HU_vac_ns], 
(1/A.[HU_VACANT]) * POWER( 
CASE WHEN ((A.[HU_VACANT] - A.[HU_VACANT_SEASONAL_RECREATIONAL])/A.[HU_VACANT]) * POWER(A.[HU_VACANT_MOE], 2) < POWER(A.[HU_VACANT_MOE], 2) +     POWER(A.[HU_VACANT_SEASONAL_RECREATIONAL_MOE], 2) THEN POWER(A.[HU_VACANT_MOE],     2) + POWER(A.[HU_VACANT_SEASONAL_RECREATIONAL_MOE], 2) - (((A.[HU_VACANT] - A.    [HU_vACANT_SEASONAL_RECREATIONAL])/A.[HU_VACANT]) * POWER(A.[HU_VACANT_MOE], 2))
ELSE POWER(A.[HU_VACANT_MOE], 2) + POWER(A.    [HU_VACANT_SEASONAL_RECREATIONAL_MOE], 2) + (((A.[HU_VACANT] - A.    [HU_vACANT_SEASONAL_RECREATIONAL])/A.[HU_VACANT]) * POWER(A.[HU_VACANT_MOE], 2)) END, 0.5) AS [r_HU_vac_ns_MOE]
FROM
(SELECT 
[OUTSIDE_ROW], 
[INSIDE_ROW], 
SUM([ESTIMATE_1]) AS [HU_VACANT], 
POWER(SUM(POWER([MOE_1], 2)), 0.5) AS [HU_VACANT_MOE],
SUM([ESTIMATE_2]) AS [HU_VACANT_SEASONAL_RECREATIONAL],
POWER(SUM(POWER([MOE_2], 2)), 0.5) AS [HU_VACANT_SEASONAL_RECREATIONAL_MOE]
FROM #TEST_TABLE
GROUP BY [OUTSIDE_ROW], [INSIDE_ROW]) A
WHERE A.[HU_VACANT] > 0) B ) C 
WHERE C.[PCT] < 0.2
```

Every time I run it, I get the following error:

```
Msg 8134, Level 16, State 1, Line 533
Divide by zero error encountered.
```

However, if I take off the last line of code (the following WHERE clause) the code runs fine:

```
WHERE C.[PCT] < 0.2
```

Just from looking at my query, can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I thought I eliminated all `PCT` values that were zero with the CASE WHEN statement below so this error is baffling me:

```
 CASE WHEN B.[r_HU_vac_ns] = 0 THEN 999 ELSE B.[r_HU_vac_ns_MOE]/B.[r_HU_vac_ns] END AS [PCT]
```

If it helps, `PCT` is cast as floating point.

Thanks.

Comment: you didn't exclude zero. you excluded values BIGGER than 0.2. since `0 < 0.2` is true, `0` is still a valid result and will cause div-by-zero errors if it is in the db.

Comment: @MarcB Please re-read the question. The OP wrote "I thought I eliminated all PCT values that were zero with the CASE WHEN statement", because the CASE statement appears to prevent the divide by zero calculation. Although as Gordon Linoff writes in his answer, SQL Server may rearrange the calculations, so the CASE WHEN statements may actually be evaluated after the division is evaluated.

Answer (score 5):

SQL Server reserves the right to rearrange calculations.  That means that the calculation in a `SELECT` can happen *before* filtering occurs.  This is true even when the filters are in subqueries and CTEs.

The only way to guarantee order of calculation is `CASE`.  However, I think it is easier to just use `NULLIF()`, an ANSI standard function.  Instead of logic like this:

```
(A.[HU_VACANT] - A.[HU_VACANT_SEASONAL_RECREATIONAL])/A.[HU_VACANT] AS [r_HU_vac_ns],
```

do:

```
(A.[HU_VACANT] - A.[HU_VACANT_SEASONAL_RECREATIONAL])/NULLIF(A.[HU_VACANT], 0) AS [r_HU_vac_ns],
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of filtering out the records using

```
WHERE A.[HU_VACANT] > 0
```

You should filter out the records at root level

```
having SUM([ESTIMATE_1]) > 0
```

You could also use nullif function but that will result producing NULL where you have zero